# How to use variable in Find and grep command?

Tags: command-line, scripts, grep, find

find command to get files have part of their names as date ($Y variable that has date in the script)

```
Y=(date -d "1 day ago" "+%Y-%m-%d")
find /log/bssuser/CDR/Postpaid_CDR_Log/ -type f -name '*log_LOG_POSTPAID_CDR'*$Y*.log | grep -H '^ORA' 'log_LOG_POSTPAID_CDR'*$Y*.log
```

when run this command I got the below error:

```
grep: log_LOG_POSTPAID_CDR*date*.log: No such file or directory
```

the command can't see `$Y` as variable has date of yesterday

EX for name one of the file:

log_LOG_POSTPAID_CDR-2023-10-16_PTT_CDR.1066.20231010000509.csv_KODIAK-100.log

Comment: You want to set `Y` to the output of the `date` command. As it is, the variable `$Y` will be set to the command string itself, including the brackets. You skipped the `$` before the opening bracket. Use `Y=$(date -d "1 day ago" "+%Y-%m-%d")` instead.

Comment: @Jos please add an answer.

Comment: Furthermore, you should put `$Y` within double quotes for it to work correctly when specifying name: `... -name "*log_LOG_POSTPAID_CDR*$Y*.log"`

Comment: Finally, the grep command will not work the way you pipe it - you should probably use `xargs` - see my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of small errors and typos, as Jos and sudodus is pointing out.

First, you need to use command substitution `$()` to get the variable to work.

Secondly, use the variable inside double quotes in your `find` command.

Thirdly, if you're going to pipe the file output directly to a grep command (to grep inside the files you have found), you should use `xargs`.

So what you want should probably be like this:

```
Y=$(date -d "1 day ago" "+%Y-%m-%d")
find /log/bssuser/CDR/Postpaid_CDR_Log/ -type f -name "*log_LOG_POSTPAID_CDR*$Y*.log" | xargs grep -H '^ORA'
```